# Solve for recursion in Sympy

Tags: python, recursion, sympy, solver

Given

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w = symbols('a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w')
c = (b/100) * a
e = (d/100) * a
g = (f/100) * a
i = (a + c + e + g) * (h/100)
l = (a + c + e + g + i + j) * (k/100)
m = a + c + e + g + i + j + l
o = m * (n/100)
p = m + o
s = w * (r/100)
v = (p + q + s + t) * (u/100)
w = p + q + s + t + v
```

if I use `subs` like

```
 x = w.subs({a : 1727305.7, b: 27, d : 1.13, f: 0, h : 2, j: 23909.68, k : 0.027, n : 0,  q: 1000, r : 3.5, t: 1988.77, u : 13.13 })
```

`x` ends up being `0.0395955*w + 2584992.38639031`

How can i solve for recursion of w by setting a iteration limit (eg: In Excel We can set it solve it recursively with a iteration limit of 10) and the result would be `26,91,566`

Comment: Hint: In your first line, you could also use `from sympy.abc import *`.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: this was modified to be pasted to stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a slightly more general way to do this kind of problem, by simply solving the full set of equations represented by the equations and the givens. I've transformed the equalities into expressions which must be equal to zero:

```
eqs = [
    c - (b/100) * a,
    e - (d/100) * a,
    g - (f/100) * a,
    i - (a + c + e + g) * (h/100),
    l - (a + c + e + g + i + j) * (k/100),
    m - (a + c + e + g + i + j + l),
    o - m * (n/100),
    p - (m + o),
    s - w * (r/100),
    v - (p + q + s + t) * (u/100),
    w - (p + q + s + t + v),
    ]
```

So that's the equations. Now we need to specify the givens:

```
givens = [a - 1727305.7,
          b - 27,
          d - 1.13, 
          f - 0,
          h - 2,
          j - 23909.68,
          k - 0.027, 
          n - 0,
          q - 1000,
          r - 3.5,
          t - 1988.77,
          u - 13.13]
```

Finally we can just solve the full set of equations

```
solve(eqs + givens)
```

The result is

```
[{f: 0.0,
  g: 0.0,
  i: 44263.9358682000,
  j: 23909.6800000000,
  u: 13.1300000000000,
  q: 1000.00000000000,
  d: 1.13000000000000,
  a: 1727305.70000000,
  e: 19518.5544100000,
  p: 2281986.37928871,
  l: 615.970010505114,
  w: 2691566.29981462,
  s: 94204.8204935118,
  k: 0.0270000000000000,
  b: 27.0000000000000,
  n: 0.0,
  m: 2281986.37928871,
  o: 0.0,
  v: 312386.330032405,
  h: 2.00000000000000,
  r: 3.50000000000000,
  c: 466372.539000000,
  t: 1988.77000000000}]
```

The nice thing about this way of doing things is that we don't need to distinguish ahead of time which things will be handled by `.subs` and which by equalities. The only downside is if there isn't a closed form solution. The iteration method in Excel would still work then, but this would fail.

If speed is important and you know that the things that are given will not change, it is faster and simpler only to solve the very last equation:

```
c,e,g,i,j,l,m,o,p,s,u = symbols('c,e,g,i,j,l,m,o,p,s,u')

a = 1727305.7
b = 27
d = 1.13
f = 0
h = 2
j = 23909.68
k = 0.027
n = 0
q = 1000
r = 3.5
t = 1988.77
u = 13.13
c = (b/100) * a
e = (d/100) * a
g = (f/100) * a
i = (a + c + e + g) * (h/100)
l = (a + c + e + g + i + j) * (k/100)
m = a + c + e + g + i + j + l
o = m * (n/100)
p = m + o
s = w * (r/100)
v = (p + q + s + t) * (u/100)
```

Now,

```
solve(w - (p + q + s + t + v), w)
```

yields

```
[2691566.29981462]
```

Lastly, if you pre-solve the equations, you then get an expression which you can substitute into later:

```
sol = solve(w - (p + q + s + t + v), w)[0]
sol.subs({a : 1727305.7, b: 27, d : 1.13, f: 0, h : 2, j: 23909.68, k : 0.027, n : 0,  q: 1000, r : 3.5, t: 1988.77, u : 13.13 })
```

Comment: While the solution is functional, this takes around 10s to compute when debugging, are there any flags which can be set to speed it up

Comment: @NareshJois Strange. It only takes 700 ms on my machine. I've added an alternative solution which only solves the last equation.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment about time, and thanks for both the solutions